# Does an arithmetic operation copy the value of the variables involved?

Tags: python, multithreading, computer-science, symbolic-math

Let's say I have a function "f(x) -> x.value + 1", where x is the reference to an object or data structure, and I call it one million times, asynchronously and in parallel. It's possible that at some point I will have one million copies of "value" in the main memory?

I'm assuming any programming language that supports true parallelism is being used.

Comment: This is going to come down to implementation details. In CPython, there will only ever be one 256 object here (small integers are cached). Your code shouldn't produce any copies of that value. i.e. `x + y` will not copy either `x` or `y` (I suppose, an implementation *could* do that internally, but CPython does not, nor does any other implementation probably)

Comment: Note, there is no parallelism in this code. CPython has a global interpreter lock

Comment: The python example was more for helping clarify the question. I think there must be some consensus about what happens at the machine code level, maybe? I have multiple processors using the same value in an operation, in parallel. Does the value needs to be copied in the ram at some point? Or maybe just at the registers' level?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga No parallelism? So maybe it was a bad example then.

Comment: As a side note, CPython currently keeps a single pre-built copy of the integers -5 to 256. if your example was `{"value":257}` then this optimization would not be part of the discussion.

Comment: @DouglasMonteiro You *do not have multiple processors using the same value in parallel*. The only way to do that in CPython for interpreter-level code is to use `multiprocessing`, which creates entirely seperate processes (so yes, each process would have it's own memory)

Comment: There is no parallelism because you called the function serially in `request_list = [sum_random(d)] * 1000` before starting an async operation. And, async is cooperative multitasking - an example would only have parallelism if it waits internally. maybe a `await asyncio.sleep(0)` for test case.

Comment: @tdelaney Thanks, I will edit the question with this! Also, I need an example where there's no global interpreter lock, do you have any idea how I can change my example to obtain that? I would need to use other language?

Comment: @DouglasMonteiro **you can't**. That is an aspect of the CPython runtime that cannot be changed at the Python level (you could write a C-extension and call that from Python and that can do whatever you want, but Python level code running on the Python interpreter will always run one thread at a time)

Comment: @tdelaney yes, although as I pointed out, even if you used an integer in the non-cached range, e.g. 1337, it would not be copied here

Comment: I'm confused, @juanpa.arrivillaga says that I can't achive parallelism, tdelaney says that I can only achieve parallelism if "it waits internally".

Comment: The global interpreter lock is fundamental to CPython. Its not used in jython (python implemented in java - still at python version 2.7, so dead) or ironpython (implemented in C# - at version 3.4 so almost dead) and I think pypy. Pypy or one of its deriviates could be interesting.

Comment: @tdelaney very informative. Thanks! But would you happen to know if the variable would need to be copied if true parallelism was a thing here?

Answer (score 1):

There will only be one `256` object and one `{"value": 256}` object, but each called function will have a reference to the dict and a temporary reference to 256 when `d["value"]` is active. In cpython, a reference is just a pointer (likely 8 bytes), which is smaller than a python `int` object, but still not zero.

When a function is called, python creates an object to hold an instance of that call which includes a namespace for local variables, and that is larger than the references to the dict and integer.

Comment: So all the calls can use, at the same time, the 256 integer value stored in the original memory address?

Comment: @DouglasMonteiro - Yes. Python never passes a pure value to a function - only references. In CPython, the called function gets C style pointers to its parameters, not the values themselves.

Comment: @DouglasMonteiro stop thinking in terms of "memory address", that is the wrong level of abstraction. Python has *objects*. And yes, the *same object* is re-used over and over. Why wouldn't it be?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga But he talked about pointers and references. How could I not think in terms of memory addresses? Also, I'm interested in knowing if the value will appear more than once in the memory ram, so I need to know in terms of memory address indeed.

Comment: Python is compiled to byte code (you could do `print(dis.dis(sum_random))` to see some) and each byte code is executed by C code. These will use the local stack and processor registers to perform their operations. Its also common for operations to call C code (for instance `int` is implemented in C) which will also use the stack and registers.

Comment: Python's async code will not interrupt a single byte code or called C function. But A C function may release the global interpreter lock letting another thread run, so you can get some parallelism there.

Comment: Ok, so maybe my sin was to use python for the example. I honestly don't know a lot of python. I thought that every single call to an async function would be performed in parallel, as long I don't add the "await" before the call.

Comment: @DouglasMonteiro - Python's aysnc is a form of cooperative multitasking on a single thread. There is an underlying event loop that either calls functions or restarts coroutines that have awaited for some reason. Frequently the wait is happening when the code is calling an async enabled io operation. So for instance, calling `open` in an async routine is bad (no other tasks run) while `aiofiles.open` is good. Perhaps it would have been better to implement a separate async version of python - what we have is a mine field.

Comment: @DouglasMonteiro yea, that is absolutely incorrect. It is a common misconception about asynchronous programming, many people confuse "asynchronous" and "parallel". Although asynchronous *can* be parallel, in CPython, it isn't. Note, this is the same as in, say, node.js (which is single-threaded)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga That's so interesting! I had no idea, seriously. Thank you very much. But supposing true parallelism. Do you know if the variable would need to be copied?

Comment: And as an old school programmer who has worked on multiple async (not parallel) code bases, it has its advantages. The locks and similar control structures used to keep parallel programming safe, go away, along with the risks that go along with them. Deadly embrace, inversion of priority, lots of nasty gotchas evaporate.

Comment: C would be truly parallel. And if we were thinking in terms as a pointer to an integer, the pointer would be copied a lot, but the integer itself could potentially only be moved into cpu registers for operations. But it depends on the operation. If its used to call another function by value, for instance, it would be pushed on the stack.

Comment: @tdelaney gotcha! So even if is created one process for each call, as long there's no, for example, call to another function by value, the variable would only be moved to the registers, but no copy on the RAM would be required. Is that it? Could you add this to your answer so I can accept it?

Comment: If you create a new process... it depends on the operating system. Unlix like systems have copy-on-write (COW) subprocesses, meaning a memory page would only be copied if it is written to. Windows creates new processes - so the int would be copied. Even on Unix, if any value in a RAM page is touched the entire (usually 4096 bytes) is copied. And since the `int` is in python's heap with other values, it may well be copied then. Getting things to scale in the millions is hard.

Comment: `int` is a tough use case because in C, an int is usually the same size as a pointer to int. In C, its frequently better to pass the int than a pointer to an int. In python its larger because you have a python header that is part of every object python creates. So, passing the pointer like python does is faster.